# Titanium app running on titanium sdk 3.4.0 but not on titanium sdk 3.5.0

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Titanium app is running fine on titanium sdk 3.4.0 but when I updated titanium sdk to 3.5.0,the app is installing on device but application does not starts.I have not used any module,so I do not converted any module to 64 bit.

What should I do? I have created adhoc provisioning profile to test the app on device,but after updating to 3.5.0 titanium sdk,the app is not working..

Thanks...

Comment: Is the app not working in case of simulator too?

Comment: mention the errors which you receive

Comment: On simulator its working,no error generating...i generated ipa file and then I created link on diawi.com,then I installed the app on the device added in the provisioning profile.Then,the app installed fine on device,the application starts also but after that no screen displays